# Omnisharp in VS Code produces a lot of warnings about a Unity project. Why?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Omnisharp in VS Code produces a lot of warnings about a Unity project. Why?

When I open a script in VS Code from a Unity Editor here is what I see:

[image]

The Omnisharp produces warning. Here are a few of them:

```
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.VSCode.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'UnityEngine.UI.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
...
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Expected project reference c:\Projects\Unity\Combo Bombo\Unity.2D.Sprite.Editor.csproj to be already loaded for project Assembly-CSharp
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Expected project reference c:\Projects\Unity\Combo Bombo\Unity.2D.Tilemap.Editor.csproj to be already loaded for project Assembly-CSharp
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Expected project reference c:\Projects\Unity\Combo Bombo\Unity.TextMeshPro.csproj to be already loaded for project Assembly-CSharp
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Expected project reference c:\Projects\Unity\Combo Bombo\UnityEditor.UI.csproj to be already loaded for project Assembly-CSharp
```

Does anyone know why the `warnings` happen and how could I fix them?

I am not sure what else should I provide for a successful diagnose of the issue. So, could you, please, ask in comments in case I have to tell something else about the issue for a successful diagnose.

I have the `1.42.1` VS Code version:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warnings is a known [Visual Studio Code Editor 1.1.4](https://forum.unity.com/threads/visual-studio-code-editor-1-1-4-error-the-referenced-project-does-not-exist.806628/) bug, you can ignore it. For me, downgrading to version **1.1.3** of the package fixed the problems.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you happen to know the downgrade process for the VS Code? The process is referenced in the linked question. Also, I actually have not the `1.1.4` version. I will update my question.

Comment: @qqqqqqq [Visual Studio Code Editor 1.1.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwqV8.png) is a unity package, not the actual program.

Answer (score 6):

This issue has also been solved in `1.2.0`. Just update your vs code package to this version via the package manager. Then regenerate your project files by navigating to Edit -> Preferences -> Regenerate Project Files. Reopening a .cs file should then solve your problem.

Comment: Confirmed, this is working for me with 1.2.0, which is current latest (April 2020)

Comment: The problem is persisting on Mac os, I'm at version 1.44.2, any ideas?

Comment: "Edit -> Preferences -> Regenerate Project Files" was really helpful for me in the frustrating scenario that some of my classes were failing to be referenced, many thanks for posting!

Answer (score 3):

If you downgrade to 1.1.3 and right after upgrade to 1.2.0 your problem should be fixed!

Answer (score -1):

The fix that worked for me was closing VS Code, ticking "Generate all .csproj files" under Edit > Preferences > External tools, then going ti Assets > Open C# Project.

Additionally, in VS Code, make sure that .csproj and .sln file extensions aren't excluded under Edit > User (tab) > Text Editor > Files > Files: Exclude.