# VS Code enable Intellisense for C# files in Unity Project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

VS Code's Intellisense doesn't work for my C# files from my Unity Project. It doesn't even hightlight syntax errors as you can see in the image.
The C# extension and also other extensions are installed and enabled.

What could be the issue?

[image: Installed and Enabled Extensions]

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62949390/13374682

Answer (score 0):

It works when:

1. You go into Unity's Package Manager
2. Search for vscode
3. Update the Visual Studio Code Editor to 1.1.3

So in the end it should look as follows:
[image: Package Manager Window]