# Visual studio not giving Hints (intellisense) when i opening the c# scripts through unity,

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I recently installed unity ,but I didn't install visual studio with it because I already have installed.
I simply opened unity and I goes to **Edit > Preferences > External script editor**  and  I selected Visual studio code .  But  when I opening my scripts, visual studio not giving hints for my c# code.

[image: unity Externals tools]
[image: Visual studio code]

Comment: If you had searched SO you would see this comes up many times. Visual studio is not the same as visual studio code and the code editor does not seem to set up as easily as visual studio itself this has been answered many times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code IntelliSense not working for Unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823422/vs-code-intellisense-not-working-for-unity3d)

Comment: yes ..it worked ..

Comment: this vs code not worked, i downloaded the another one and everything working fine

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the appropriate [targeting pack](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity#_enabling-code-completion-for-recent-versions-of-unity) for Unity. That article also has some other helpful extensions to install when developing in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is just open it and close it.

What i mean by that is go to **Assets > Open C# Project**

Once VSCode opened, wait for 1 min, try to write something like **Rigidbody**.
If intellisense is working it will start giving you hints, if it's still not working

Do the process one more time,

You can refer to these pictures where how VSCode tells you whether Intellisense is working or not.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ6uL.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need to install snippets for Unity in VS code.
Open VS code. Go to Extensions(ctrl+shift+X).
In search field you need to write unity
Then click to Unity Code Snippets and install it in window bellow.
Then you will be able to see Intelesence !

Comment: maybe you will need to install C#
ms-dotnettools.csharp tool too.

Comment: this question is  about VisualStudio not vs-code

Comment: But on Screenshot it`s VS code) If you need to Intelesense in VS, you need to go to Extensions > Manage Extensions > in Find field add 'Unity', then download Unity File Templates and Snippets. Then, in Unity, preferences>External tools> choice Visual Studio in External script editor. Then reopen VS, await few seconds, and you will see Intelesense )